# Why my ipad mini 1 (A1455 Late 2012) is slower than my ipad 3(A1416 early 2012)?

Tags: ipad

My ipad mini 1 (A1455 Late 2012) is very slow and it is even much slower than my ipad 3(A1416 Early 2012). Both are running iOS 9.3.5. Why? I thought later model should be faster.

I've tried to reset the ipad mini several times, and removed most of the apps, but it is still very slow. Sometimes it does not respond to the taps or delays a few seconds. Web page loading is also very slow.

Any idea and solutions? Wanted to Jailbreak to see but it requires donation.

Thanks in advance.

Model check:
https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201471

Comment: Jailbreaking does not require donation. What method are you trying to use to jailbreak?

Comment: It is clear iPad mini got a slower CPU, so won't bother jailbreak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iPad 1st Generation has an A5 processor while the iPad 3 has A5X (Much faster). This is very similar to iPad Pro 2017 and the iPad 2018. Even though the 2018 iPad is the latest, it doesn't mean it is faster than previous models. It's a matter of the processor itself. In fact, I have an iPod 5G and it contains the same processor as iPad 1st gen. It is kind of slow.